Error: Unable to resolve module missing-asset-registry-path
I am encountering this error when trying to run my react native app:
Unable to resolve module missing-asset-registry-path from /Users/user/Desktop/project/node_modules/@react-navigation/elements/lib/commonjs/assets/back-icon.png: missing-asset-registry-path could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
> 1 | �PNG
  2 | 
  3 | 
  4 | IHDR`H����IDATx���1��

I have this version of react native:
"react-native": "0.73.6"
I think this error appeard when I added eslint configurations in my project. How can I solve this?

Had the same issue, was solved by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78426573/10722284
TLDR - upgrade your metro.config.js and it should do the trick!
 * Metro configuration for React Native
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 */

const { getDefaultConfig, mergeConfig } = require('@react-native/metro-config');

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

const {
  resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts },
} = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

const config = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: true,
      },
    }),
    babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('react-native-svg-transformer'),
  },
  resolver: {
    assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== 'svg'),
    sourceExts: [...sourceExts, 'svg'],
  },
};

module.exports = mergeConfig(defaultConfig, config);


Solution 1:- Sometimes, caching issues can cause this error, you need to clear the cache and restart the metro bundler.
npx react-native start –reset-cache

Solution 2:- Delete the node_modules and package-lock.json file and for iOS delete the Pods and Podfile.lock
Run these command
npm install
cd ios
pod install
cd ..
npx react-native run-android
npx react-native run-ios

Note:- If the above solutions do not work, try to change the metro.config.js file.
module.exports = {
 transformer: {
   getTransformOptions: async () => ({
     transform: {
       experimentalImportSupport: false,
       inlineRequires: true,
      },
    }),
  },
};

